# PHP Variables/Functions in saved HTML

Tags: php, html

Apologies on the title couldn't explain probably as a title.

In my project I am creating a modular system *(loosely used)* for UI components.

For this example I have a template table which holds a button 'template' in HTML with 'pre-named' variables and functions which I aim to be initialised and called upon output;

```
<?php
$icon = "{{myIcon}}";
echo $this->getTemplate('icon-button');
?>

(Stored in MYSQL & Outputted like)
<div><button class="<?= $this->getGlobalClass('button') ?>">
<i class="<?= $icon ?>"></i>
</button>
</div>

(How I would like)
<div><button class="myButtonClass">
<i class="myDesiredIcon"></i>
</button>
</div>
```

Even though the variables have been defined within the scope, they are not being outputted. Instead I am receiving the mark-up as it is stored.

How can I resolve this/or find an alternative?

Hope this made sense and thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: May want to check out [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)

Comment: or use a proper template system

Comment: @Dagon, I sure will use a 'proper templating system', however I am now curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the eval function like this:

```
<?php
$icon = "{{myIcon}}";
eval('?> ' . $this->getTemplate('icon-button') . ' <?php ');
?>
```

Comment: Why is eval() 'evil'? Sure, if this use was for user input or data from a client side that is ultimately unvalidated, i.e from GET_[] or POST_[], I would agree. However, its not. Please explain why it would be in this context? and please provide an alternative if possible.

Comment: Apart from the security issue of executing code from unknown sources, you may get inconsistent results, i.e. code in the template could mess with your globals, etc. At least with a templating system, you remove the security issue as well as the application integrity issue. Never trust other people's code! I have seen a lot of server malware exploit eval.